# Give different tickFormat() according to time period displayed?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis

Is it possible to give a different `tickFormat()` type for my axis labels depending on the time period that is being displayed?

For example if th time range is a day, I would like to show hours `tickFormat(d3.time.format('%I'))`

If it is a week I would like to show days `tickFormat(d3.time.format('%A'))`

If it is a month I would like to show weeks `tickFormat(d3.time.format('%W'))`

And so on and so on...

Comment: You would need to check the range of the domain and set the format accordingly.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks, I was just checking if there was a built in way I have missed.

Comment: The closest thing are [multi-scale time formats](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176), but those won't work for what you're trying to do.